# Best way to persist a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, database

I have a map that need to be persisted, i believe no need to use a database to persist this map engine.
 so i decided to use a simple text file. and the text file will be loaded at the start of the application and any new entry added to the map will be persisted to the file.
how i can delete or update record in this file without rewriting the whole map to the file. and is it efficient to use a file instead of light database engine(derby, h2..)?
note the size of the map will not exceed 1000 record.

Comment: You could serialize to json, save it as a text file, and then read back to map from the json data, Jackson or Gson would work for this...

Comment: can Gson be used to update a record in the middle of the file ? i want to know that before reading the full tutorial, actually i don't know Gson.

Comment: If the partial update is important, then use a database. Otherwise you end up writing one.